# Android Method execution time using AspectJ

Tags: android, aspectj

My Android code has several methods and I am finding each method execution time in Android using AspectJ. For this I am using -

```
pointcut methodCalls(): 
      execution(* com.example.buttontestaspect..*(..))&& !within(com.example.buttontestaspect.testbutton);

      before(): methodCalls(){
     start = System.currentTimeMillis();//Start of execution time of method
          Log.d("hi", "start = " + start);
         }

          after(): methodCalls(){
     double end = System.currentTimeMillis();//End of execution time of method
              Log.d("hi", "end = " + end);
              double t = (end - start);
         }
```

Whenever a new method execution starts happening, I am checking the value of start time in before(). It is always constant and equals to 1.445714916545E12. Is this correct or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

System.currentTimeMillis() returns a long, but you're inserting it into a double.  I'd try changing it to a long and see if that does the trick.